# Unity test/Play mode window problem

Tags: unity

I tried to find an answer to his problem but i wasn't successful. When i press play to test my game, instead of the play mode going to the Game tab and play the game there, with all the unity tabs and options still on the screen, it goes almost full screen, all of the unity window goes to the game mode and i can't see anything but the game, to see the scene, options, etc.. again i need to stop the play mode. For example, if i want to test triggers in play mode, i can't because all i see is the game window. How can i test the game just in the Game tab? Perhaps i changed some setting.

I'm not sure if im explaining my problem correctly.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is the feature of unity. There is a small little surprising button does exist at the top of Game tab, called "Maximize on Play". You can disable this feature by pressing it again.

[image]

Comment: It wasn't enabled, i already tried that.

Comment: Before play:
http://s13.postimg.org/tb68pmecn/image.png
After:
http://s29.postimg.org/yhi169ggn/image.png

Comment: Strange man....

Comment: Then it is not going full screen. Well, you can update your Unity Editor.. May be this will resolve this strange issue.. Or I don't know if this is happening due to any modification in settings\